# What is the meaning of the set $\mathbb R^{-n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

In the system of ODEs below, I have (if I'm correct) the function 
$$
f:\mathbb R^{n(k-1)}\times \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n \tag 1
$$

From the cartesian product I can write $\mathbb R^{n(k-1)}=\mathbb R^{nk}\times \mathbb R^{-n}$.

But what is the meaning of the set $\mathbb R^{-n}$?

Bakground:

> I found $f$ from the following system of ODEs:
>   \begin{align}
> x_1^{(k)}&=f_1(t,x,x^{(1)},\dots, x^{(k-1)})\\
> & \,\,\, \vdots \\
> x_n^{(k)}&=f_n(t,x,x^{(1)},\dots, x^{(k-1)}),\\
> \end{align}
>   where $x:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and $t\in \mathbb R$.

*My work:*

Because $x:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, I also have $x^{(1)},\dots, x^{(k-1)}, x^{(k)}:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$.

And for each component $f_i$, $i=1, \dots, n$, I have:

$x^{(1)},\dots, x^{(k-1)}$ are $(k-1 )$ functions with $n$ components each, so $n(k-1)$ and therefore $\mathbb R^{n(k-1)}$.

$x$ is a function with $n$ components, so $\mathbb R^n$ and $t$ is a scalar, $t\in \mathbb R$.

Thus,
$$
f:\mathbb R^{n(k-1)}\times \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n
$$

Is the domain of the function correct? If so, what is the meaning of $\mathbb R^{-n}$?

Comment: "From the cartesian product I can write $\mathbb R^{n(k-1)}=\mathbb R^{nk}\times \mathbb R^{-n}$" — Why are you convinced of this?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. You just assert that it does, then ask what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\mathbb{R}^{a} \times \mathbb{R}^b = \mathbb{R}^{a+b}$ is only defined for nonnegative $a$ and $b$.  That doesn't automatically extend to negative “exponents” in a meaningful way.

If there were such a set $\mathbb{R}^{-n}$, then $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{-n}$ would have to be $\mathbb{R}^0$.  But $\mathbb{R}^n$ is infinite, and $\mathbb{R}^0$ has cardinality one, making the equation impossible.  For if $\mathbb{R}^{-n}$ is nonempty, then $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{-n}$ is infinite, and if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is empty, then $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{-n}$ is empty.

Comment: $\mathbb R^a$ means functions from sets with $a$ elements into $\mathbb R$. So that give $a$ reals. So I think $\mathbb R^0$ is rather $\varnothing$ than $\{0\}$ (it gives zero real numbers).

Comment: @zwim There is exactly one function from $\{\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, namely the empty function. (This is why, by the way, "$0^0=1$" is a reasonable definition.) So $\mathbb{R}^0$ should refer to the set containing only the empty map, which is different from the emptyset. Re: the answer, the Cartesian product of an infinite set with another set *can* be finite if the other set in question is empty.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: That's a good point.  I've revised the answer to make the argument less sloppy.